# uwp CredentialPicker not showing untill update

Tags: c#, uwp, credentials

I'm making a UWP application. When you start the application a `CredentialPicker` should pop up and the application will wait for the user to fill in his credentials.

Now the problem I have is a very weird one. When the application starts the `CredentialPicker`wont show up until the application gets an update, for example: when I start the application, switch my focus to notepad and then switch back to the application it shows up. But it won't when I just keep the application open.

The way I call the `CredentialPicker`:

```
CredentialPickerOptions options = new CredentialPickerOptions()
{
    CallerSavesCredential = true,
    AlwaysDisplayDialog = true,
    AuthenticationProtocol = AuthenticationProtocol.Negotiate,
    TargetName = "Patch Management",
    Message = "Please enter your credentials",
    Caption = "Patch Management"
};

var credPickerResults = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options);

if (credPickerResults.ErrorCode == 0)
{
    string username = credPickerResults.CredentialUserName;
    string password = credPickerResults.CredentialPassword;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        //Window.Current.Activate();
        PasswordVault vault = new PasswordVault();
        PasswordCredential credential = new PasswordCredential("Patch Management", username,
        password);
        vault.Add(credential);
    }
}
else
{
    Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

I cant just make the application unfocus and focus again because it waits for the `credPickerResults` and I need need to keep it synchronous because else the user can use the application while he's not authenticated.

Should I just make my own login page or is there a fix?

### EDIT

Ok, messed around with it some more and I removed a canvas with +/- 50 polygons drawn on it as a map. Now it works, but I really dont understand why because it's only that map. I have 7 more pages with maps and some of them are bigger than the one I removed. And if I remove another one it doesnt make a difference.

### EDIT 2

Nevermind the last edit, it was just a coincidence that it suddenly worked when I removed the map. It's back and have no clue why. I did find out that u can get it to show if you press the Titlebar of the application though

Comment: Sounds to me like your UI thread is blocking somehow before it even gets to a point to show the picker. When you debug, is the actual picker being reached?

Comment: @Adwaenyth Yes, it's reaching the line `var credPickerResults = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options);`.  Also it shows when I break it there because i focus the application again.

It's all very strange

Comment: Is the `await`ed method iteself causing a deadlock with something as long as the UI is focused maybe? Does it change anything when you await with `var credPickerResults = await CredentialPicker.PickAsync(options).ConfigureAwait(false);`?

Comment: @Adwaenyth I can't seem to add `ConfigureAwait(false);` to the current line... I've added `System.Threading.Tasks` but it still isn't recognised. It's inconsistent ass well, last Friday it would work after I deleted some content, but now i'm back to it and it doesnt anymore :/

Comment: I'm just going to make a custom login page. Seems to give a lot less trouble. But if anyone still knows the solution to this problem, I'd love to know.